# Extraer un dato de una tabla mysql y convertirla a string,int,boolean, etc, C#

Tags: c#, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla de productos y mediante un programa en C# quiero hacer varias operaciones con los datos de una columna llamada "precio" como calcular total, descuentos, etc. Quiero saber como puedo extraer esos datos y meterlos en una variable o un array para convertirlos en int y operarlos.

Comment: Mira [Cómo preguntar][1] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.


  [1]: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

todo depende como extraes los datos de esta tabla, recomiendo que compartes el codigo y en esta manera puede que algien te puede ayudar, Este codigo representa extracion de datos par una factura para el cliente.

```
public void LoadData()
{
    ListItem[] collection = (ListItem[])Session["SearchId"];
    dt.Columns.Add("No Reserva", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Full Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Check In", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Check Out", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Adults", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Child", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Accommodation", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(decimal));
    dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.Tables.Add(dt);
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        MNRid = int.Parse(item.Text);
        
        var FullName = ToRid.Select(d => d.Apellido).FirstOrDefault() + " " + ToRid.Select(d => d.Nombre).FirstOrDefault();
        rw = dt.NewRow();
        rw["No Reserva"] = ToRid.Select(g => g.NoReserva).FirstOrDefault();
        rw["Full Name"] = FullName;
        rw["Check In"] = ToRid.Select(g => g.CheckIn).FirstOrDefault().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        rw["Check Out"] = ToRid.Select(g => g.CheckOut).FirstOrDefault().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        rw["Adults"] = ToRid.Select(g => g.Adultos).FirstOrDefault();
        rw["Child"] = ToRid.Select(g => g.Ninios).FirstOrDefault();
        rw["Accommodation"] = ToRid.Select(g => g.Regiman.RegimenTyp).FirstOrDefault();
        rw["Total"] = ToRid.Select(g => g.PrecioTotal).FirstOrDefault();
        dt.Rows.Add(rw);

        Sum = dt.Compute("Sum(Total)", "");
        decimal NewSum = Convert.ToDecimal(Sum);
        Vat = (NewSum * 0.07M) / (1 + 0.07M);
        SumaNetto = NewSum - Vat;
    }

    GridView1.DataSource = dataSet;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    lblSuma.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00 €}", Sum);
    lbligice.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00 €}", Vat);
    lblneto.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00 €}", SumaNetto);
    lbligic.Text = "7%";
     

    lblNoFac.Text ="HLP-" + (LastNoFact + 1).ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Today.Month + "-" + DateTime.Today.Year;
    lblFechaDeFactura.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
    int MyTAID = _db.Reservas.Where(d => d.Rid == MNRid).Select(d => d.TAId).FirstOrDefault();
    var DoAdressTA = _db.TravelAgents.Where(d => d.TAId == MyTAID);
    var Entr = _db.TravelAgents.Where(d => d.TAId == 1);
    lblTAID.Text = MyTAID.ToString();
    lblTa.Text = DoAdressTA.Select(d => d.Touroperator).FirstOrDefault();
    lblCalle.Text = DoAdressTA.Select(d => d.Calle).FirstOrDefault();
    lblCP.Text = DoAdressTA.Select(d => d.CodigoPostal).FirstOrDefault();
    lblCity.Text = DoAdressTA.Select(d => d.Ciudad).FirstOrDefault();
    lblCalle.Text = DoAdressTA.Select(d => d.Calle).FirstOrDefault();
    lblState.Text = DoAdressTA.Select(d => d.Provincia).FirstOrDefault();
    lblCountry.Text = DoAdressTA.Select(d => d.Pais).FirstOrDefault();
    lblCIF.Text = DoAdressTA.Select(d => d.CIF).FirstOrDefault();

    Label1.Text = Entr.Select(d => d.Touroperator).FirstOrDefault();
    Label2.Text = Entr.Select(d => d.Calle).FirstOrDefault();
    Label3.Text = Entr.Select(d => d.CodigoPostal).FirstOrDefault();
    Label4.Text = Entr.Select(d => d.Ciudad).FirstOrDefault();
    Label5.Text = Entr.Select(d => d.Calle).FirstOrDefault();
    Label6.Text = Entr.Select(d => d.Provincia).FirstOrDefault();
    Label7.Text = Entr.Select(d => d.Pais).FirstOrDefault();
    Label8.Text = Entr.Select(d => d.CIF).FirstOrDefault();
}
```